# facet.mincount Ignored in Range Faceting

Tags: solr

I have a query that has both regular `facets` and `facet.intervals` with custom interval ranges for price. `facet.mincount` is set to 1, but Solr is still returning price ranges with 0 products.

The expected behavior is for `facet.mincount` to constrain ranges.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.mincountParameterinRangeFaceting

Solr 7.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interval facets are not range fancets - they are different concepts. When `facet.mincount` is said to restrict ranges, that does not hold for intervals.

My guess is that the reason for this is that since you're providing *all* the intervals yourself when using `facet.intervals`, you'd expect a count for all the intervals you tell Solr to give you counts for.

Range faceting however allows you to give a gap with start and end parameters, thus giving you a possibly very large set of potential values.